# OpenCV, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, g++, linker-errors

I'm trying to get OpenCV to work on my computer - for simple programs I can get it to work but for this certain program I'm unable to. The error I am getting is as follow:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccuX28GE.o
  "cv::split(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> >&)", referenced from:
      computeFocusDPC(std::vector<R_image, std::allocator<R_image> >, int, float, int, int, int, int, cv::Mat*) in ccuX28GE.o
      qDPC_loop(std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> >, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> >, double) in ccuX28GE.o
  "cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccuX28GE.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccuX28GE.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I'm trying to compile the file with the command line

`g++-5.1.0 -o qDPC_desktop qDPC.cpp -I. -std=c++11 -ggdb -fopenmp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_stitching`

I know that this error is not in the code of qDPC.cpp since it can compile on my friend's Ubuntu (I'm working on a Mac) - so I was wondering if there's something wrong with my OpenCV? I've read online online that it might be a linker problem but can't for the life of me figure this problem out. The version of OpenCV I have is 2.4.11, and the version my friend is able to compile with is 2.4.9.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that ypu are on a 64 bit os, you installed (or built) a 32bit version of OpenCV, which now you are trying to use in a 64 bit application? If this is true, then adding `-m32` to gcc would do the trick. Or installing/building the 64bit version of OpenCV.

Comment: I tried adding `-m32` to g++ but that didn't work - I got a lot more strange errors. I think my OpenCV is 64 bits -- I installed it with homebrew and I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: The only thing I can think of - is the c++11 bit. Try to compile a very simple opencv program using `cv::namedWindow` and see it it works with and without `-std=c++11`.  I suspect it will work without the `c++11`. It it doesn't work with both - try `-std=c++14` instead.

Comment: Just tried that and didn't work without -std=c++11 or with -std=c++14.